# Circular parent/child relationship in database

Tags: database-design

I have a parent with many children, which is fine.  Against each parent I am trying to store a default_child.  I want to make the default_child mandatory however I can not think how to do this.

Creating the parent first would mean violating the mandatory default_child condition.  Creating the child first would mean violating it's FK condition.

How do others deal with this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints can typically be marked "deferrable", which means you can ask the database to defer checking them until commit time.  That lets you resolve situations like this one where a constraint needs to be violated temporarily while building up the transaction, but will be satisfied again by the time you're ready to commit.

Comment: Thanks Wyzard.  Just checked the MySQL manual and didn't see any reference to deferrable.  Any idea if it's supported in MySQL?

Comment: Kim, you're right, it looks like MySQL doesn't support deferring constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Parents must exist before they have children.  True in life; true in databases.

If you want to ensure that every item you insert into the table gets a child by default, then do this using a trigger which executes immediately after the parent record is inserted.

Be careful, though: If your parent and child records are in the same table, then every time you insert a child, the trigger will fire again, creating a child of that child; which will trigger the insertion of a child of the child of the child...

Comment: "Parents must exist before they have children." Not exactly true in database terms. In principle a foreign key constraint means only that there is no child row *without* a corresponding parent. In other words they must exist *simultaneously*, not necessarily one before the other. Unfortunately SQL cannot support this and does in fact require the parent rows first. This may seem like a minor detail but in fact SQL's referential intergrity support is seriously weakened as a result of this one simple limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if every DBMS does this, but I'd expect that I can break invariants inside of a transaction and that it just needed to be right at the commit point.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fundamental limitation of SQL that it cannot support this. The nearest you can get is to disable one or more of the constraints temporarily - for instance by using a deferrable constraint.

A possible compromise is to remove the referencing column to its own table so it references both of your current tables. Then you only insert a row to this new table after the others have been populated. The constraint would still be optional of course - it's just that you wouldn't need a nullable column to implement it.